# Fourier series expansion $\sin^{2m-1} (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I can't calculate the coefficients of the Fourier. Integral turns out to be very difficult. Are there any tips on how to calculate them more easily?  $\sin^{2m-1} (x), m \in \mathbb{N}$

Also I need to find the sum of the row $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (C^{m-n}_{2m-1})^2 $$

m here is the same as for sin.

Comment: You can get the Fourier series directly without integrations: write (for any $n\in \Bbb{N}$) $\sin^n x = \left(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^n$, expand via the Binomial Theorem. The final simplified answer will involve no cosine terms.

Comment: (No cosine terms for $n$ odd as in your question, that is.) Use the fact that $e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx} = 2i\sin kx$ and make sure you know how to deal with $i^k$ for integers $k$.